# How do I open files for manipulation via command line, in Audacity, using Powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell, audacity, named-pipe

Creating macros for Audacity is easy enough as they can be put together with the UI of the program itself.

However, opening files via command line (in order to apply macros on them) is less obvious.

I should be using named pipes, but I have no idea where to start. Can you please provide a simple script that opens a MP3 file, and applies a filter or a macro on it, and saves the result?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Audacity only has limited command-line support. The only current
> command-line functions are that you can open audio files or Audacity
> project files (including multiple files) by passing them as arguments.
>
> The following options are also supported:
>
> -help display a brief list of command line options
>
> -version display the Audacity version number
>
> -test run "Benchmark" diagnostics tests
>
> -blocksize set the Audacity blocksize for writing files to disk of nnn bytes
> https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?t=77335

This was in 2014, not sure how much has changed since then

You should check out https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html and https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting_reference.html

Comment: apparently mod-script-pipe can be used with powershell, which is sort of command line

Answer (score 0):

Opening files via the command-line is easy:

```
"\path\to\audacity.exe" "\path\to\audio-file"
```

If you prefer to make Audacity your preferred utility for opening,
say, `.mp3` files, you may do so via right-click any one such file
and select *Open with > Choose another app*.
You could then open these files by a double-click in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Or in PowerShell, use the `&` [call operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-):

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Audacity\audacity.exe" "D:\Music\ACDC\Highway To Hell.mp3"
```